# Bend modifier not working?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Im trying to bend this plane into a hemisphere but its not bending correctly and i cant figure out why.
one half bends upwards and the other one bends downwards. what am i doing wrong?[image]

Comment: Apply the rotation of your object or rotate it in Edit mode on the Z axis or change the modifier's Axis?

Comment: Thanks! That worked :)